# Find the range of $F(x)=\frac 3{2-x^2}$

Tags: functions

I know that my approach is incorrect, but can someone tell me why exactly it is wrong?

---

Find the range of $F(x) = \frac{3}{2-x^2}$.

$$x^2 \ge 0$$
$$-x^2 \le 0$$
$$2-x^2 \le 2$$

If $x^2 \le 2$,

$$\frac{3}{2-x^2} \ge \frac{3}{2} \implies [\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$$

If $x^2 > 2$,

$$\frac{3}{2-x^2} < \frac{3}{2} \implies (-\infty, \frac{3}{2})$$

$\therefore$ The range of $\frac{3}{2-x^2}$ is $(-\infty, \frac{3}{2}) \cup [\frac{3}{2}, \infty)$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I can agree that $2-x^2\le 2$ for all $x$, but then I don't exactly understand how you prove: 1) that for all $y\ge\frac 32$ there is some $x$ such that $x^2\le 2$ and $\frac 3{2-x^2}=y$; 2) that for all $y<\frac 32$ there is some $x$ such that $x^2> 2$ and $\frac 3{2-x^2}=y$.

Comment: If $x^2>2$, then $2-x^2<0$, so that in this case $F(x) < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that $\frac{3}{2-x^2} < \frac{3}{2}$ does not mean that the function can take all values up to $1.5$. For example, let's set $\frac{3}{2-x^2}=1$ and find $x$ that satisfies this: $3=2-x^2 \implies x^2=-1$. There is no such $x$. One of the ways of finding range of a function is to find domain of its inverse (if it exists). Right away, you should notice that the function cannot be zero so its range cannot be all real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that you found the range to be the set of all real numbers.  As Sassatelli Guiulio indicated in the comments, you have not established that there is a value of $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y$ for each real number $y$.  Also, note that you considered values of $x$ such that $x^2 = 2$.  However, those values of $x$ are not in the domain since they make the denominator equal to zero.

The domain of a rational function is the set of all real numbers except those that make the denominator equal to zero.  The denominator is equal to zero if
\begin{align*}
2 - x^2 & = 0\\
2 & = x^2\\
\sqrt{2} & = |x|\\
\sqrt{2} & = \pm x
\end{align*}
Hence, the domain of the function is
$$\text{Dom}_f = (-\infty, -\sqrt{2}) \cup (-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}) \cup (2, \infty)$$

Suppose $y$ in the range of the function.  Then there is a real number $x$ in the domain such that
\begin{align*}
F(x) & = y\\
\frac{3}{2 - x^2} & = y\\
3 & = 2y - x^2y\\
x^2y - 2y + 3 & = 0
\end{align*}
which is a quadratic equation in $x$ unless $y = 0$.  If $y = 0$, then $3 = 0$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $0$ is not in the range.

A quadratic equation has real-valued roots if its discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$.  For the quadratic equation $x^2y - 2y + 3 = 0$, $y \neq 0$ is in the range if there exists a real number $x$ in the domain such that
\begin{align*}
\Delta & \geq 0\\
0^2 - 4y(-2y + 3) & \geq 0\\
-4y(-2y + 3) & \geq 0\\
4y(-2y + 3) & \leq 0\\
4y(2y - 3) & \geq 0
\end{align*}
The inequality is satisfied when both terms have the same sign.  This occurs if $y \leq 0$ or $y \geq 3/2$.  However, we know that $y \neq 0$.  Thus, the range of the function is
$$\text{Ran}_f = (-\infty, 0) \cup [3/2, \infty)$$